# Newbie issue with loops

Tags: python, sum, range

I am brain dead on trying to do the following task in Python(3.) Please help.

Write a loop that calculates the total of the following series of numbers: 1/30 + 2/29 + 3/27 +⋯+ 29/2 + 30/1.

```
for numerator in range(1, 31, 1):
    denominator = (31 - numerator)
    quotient = numerator / denominator
    print(quotient)
```

I can produce the quotient of each but am lost on how to efficiently find the sum.

Comment: SO is not a code generator :)

Comment: This was one of my first exposures to programming. Looking back now, this question is embarrassing. :-X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, so I'll give you a few hints.

```
# initialize a total variable to 0 before the loop

for numerator in range(1, 31, 1):
    denominator = (31 - numerator)
    quotient = numerator / denominator
    print(quotient)
    # update the total inside the loop (add the quotient to the total)

# print the total when the loop is complete
```

If you want to see a more Pythonic (idomatic) solution, see zhangxaochen's answer.  ;)

Answer (score 4):

For efficiency:

```
In [794]: sum(i*1.0/(31-i) for i in range(1, 31)) # i*1.0 is for backward compatibility with python2
Out[794]: 93.84460105853213
```

If you have to do that in a loop explicitly, see @Bill's hints ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0
for numerator in range(1, 31, 1):
    denominator = (31 - numerator)
    quotient = numerator / denominator
    print(quotient)
    total += quotient
print/return(total)
```

Be aware you are going to have some rounding going on and may get an answer you aren't expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Do this to keep track of summation.

```
total = 0

for numerator in range(1, 31, 1):
    denominator = (31 - numerator)
    quotient = numerator / denominator
    total = total + quotient

print(total)
```